# Using class on std:sort()

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, struct

An example from here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Shows that

```
struct myclass {
  bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (i<j);}
} myobject;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);               // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33

  // using object as comp
  std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);     //(12 26 32 33 45 53 71 80)
}
```

This works fine, however I am trying to use class instead of structure. So what I am doing is:

CardComparer class:

```
bool CardComparer::operator() (Card* firstCard, Card* secondCard) {
    this->firstCard = firstCard;
    this->secondCard = secondCard;
    if (firstCard->GetRank() == secondCard->GetRank()) {
        return firstCard->GetSuit() > secondCard->GetSuit();
    }
    else {
        return firstCard->GetRank() > secondCard->GetRank();
    }
}
```

and this is main:

```
CardComparer* compare;
compare = new CardComparer();
sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(), compare->operator());
```

I am getting this long error:

```
hand.cpp: In member function 'void Hand::AddCard(Card*)':
hand.cpp:60:54: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<Card*>::iterator, std::vector<Card*>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
hand.cpp:60:54: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from hand.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5463:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5463:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
hand.cpp:60:54: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from hand.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5499:5: note: void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Card**, std::vector<Card*> >; _Compare = bool (CardComparer::*)(Card*, Card*)]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5499:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'bool (CardComparer::*)(Card*, Card*)'
```

I couldn't really find a solution because if i modify the sample and keep it as a struct it works fine, but does not work when i convert it into a class.

Comment: A structure *is* a class. You mean you're trying to use a pointer (and then a member-function-pointer) when you need an object. Use an object of class/structure type instead, as the example demonstrates.

Answer (score 4):

The third argument is called a functor, and is something that can be called. Either a pointer to a function, a C++11 lambda, or an object *instance* (not pointer) with an `operator()` member function.

In your case, don't dynamically allocate the functor object on the heap, it's enough to declare it as a temporary object in the `std::sort` call:

```
std::sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(), CardComparer());
```

In the above `std::sort` call, using `CardComparer()` *creates* an object on the stack, this object is temporary and only valid while `std::sort` is running. The `std::sort` function will *call* this object, which is the same as invoking the `operator()` function on the object.

Since this comparison functor is pretty simple, it doesn't need to store any data:

```
struct CardComparer
{
    bool operator() (const Card* firstCard, const Card* secondCard) const { ... }
};
```

So no need for the member data fields.

Comment: Thanks, but I just started programming in C++ and new to classes. So, what could fix this error?

Comment: I realised that it does not actually call that operator. I intentionally put cout << "test "; in operator, and nothing gets printed out.

Comment: @user1292095 Flush the output stream: `std::cout << "test " << std::flush;`

Comment: I did it, but it does not print out anything. The problem is it does not sort anything too...

Comment: @user1292095 Can you then please edit your question to include a more complete example? Like for instance show how you declare `cards`? I also suggest you read http://sscce.org/ for tips on how to write good example code.